# FileNotFound exception when trying to access file descriptor for image captured by camera using content uri in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-contentresolver

I have written a code to get file descriptor of the image captured by Camera in Android.

```
if (file.exists()) {
                val values = ContentValues()
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath)
                return context.contentResolver.insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            } else {
                null
            }
```

This returns the content uri for the image captued by camera. When I try get file descriptor using
context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "r", null), it is throwing FileNotFound exception.

The above code was working in targetSdk 28. After upgrading targetSdk to 29, I am getting FileNotFound exception.

Comment: On Android 10 the .DATA column should not be used.

Comment: `This returns the content uri for the image captued by camera.` It looks more like: `This returns the content uri for the image to be captued by camera.`

Comment: What is filePath? Where did you get it from? How did you set up '`file`?

Comment: After capturing the photo, I am saving the photo file inside /Android/data/<my-app-package-name>. After that I am trying to get content uri from this photo file

Comment: If you have already a file you cannot afterwards ask the media store for an uri using insert() as it will create a new file. Use FileProvider if you need a content scheme uri. Also the media store keeps its hands from your app specific dir.